# How to get the text of a widget/window using python-xlib?

Tags: python, xlib

I'm trying to find the whole text that is currently being edited in gedit window. Firstly i tried to find out the current gedit tab that is focused, by using Xlib.display. Now i got an Xlib.display.window object . Now i want to find out the text that is in that particular window/widget using this window object

And my code is like this

```
import gtk, gobject, Xlib.display
currentFocus=''
def current_focused:
     global currentFocus
     display = Xlib.display.Display()
     window = display.get_input_focus().focus
     wmname = window.get_wm_name()
     wmclass = window.get_wm_class()
     if wmclass is None and wmname is None:
           window = window.query_tree().parent
           wmname = window.get_wm_name()
           if currentFocused!=wmname:
                   if window.get_wm_class()[0]=='gedit':
                          print "\nNow you are in : < %s >" % (wmname,)
                          # Here i have to find the text of the gedit's widget
      currentFocused=wmname
      return True
gobject.timeout_add(1000, current_focused)
gtk.main()
```

is there any API to get the text of a specific widget using Xlib.display.window
Please help me. I'm completely new in this area

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

WM_CLASS / WM_NAME properties are only used to provide information to a window manager ( hence WM prefix ) and not usually set on child windows. Check [GTK source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/) if edit widget sets similar properties, but in general it is not possible for external process to read edit control text